# If you remap <cr> to a function, how can you call the original <cr> in the function?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write vimscript that does something when a user presses `<cr>` (in both normal and insert mode), but which doesn't interfere with the normal effect of `<cr>`, which is to insert a line break and move the cursor to the right position on the next line (respecting smart indent or any other indent mode).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to omit `*map` where possible and you will not have such problems. This will work as expected:

```
function s:DoSomething()
    echom "Inside DoSomething"
    return "\<CR>"
    " return "\n" also works "
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <CR> <SID>DoSomething()
" If DoSomething function cannot be executed inside a textlock: "
inoremap <CR> <C-o>:call <SID>DoSomething()<CR><CR>
```

Note the `nore`, it prevents `<CR>` returned by `s:DoSomething` from being replaced again.

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand side of the mapping needs to begin with `<cr>`. Like this:

```
:imap <cr> <cr>sometext
```

Then it does not recursively trigger the mapping.

Source:
[http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*%28Part_1%29#Nested_.28recursive.29_maps](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29#Nested_.28recursive.29_maps)

*If the {rhs} of a map begins with the {lhs}, then it is not recursively replaced. For example, the following command will not create a recursive map for gq:*

```
:nmap gq gq
```